# python element tree insert is adding children twice at required position and at the end

Tags: python, xml, insert, parent-child, elementtree

I would like to add a few fields to each node in several xml files. However my script adds the childen twice, where they supposed to go and at the end of the parent.

I tried to simplify the problem to insert a field only at the first node and I still reproduce the issue. Here is the programme:

```
tree = et.parse("testdata.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
firstcountrynode= root.find("country")
newnode = et.SubElement(firstcountrynode,"Capital")
newnode.text = "Vaduz"
firstcountrynode.insert(2,newnode)
tree.write("testresult.xml")
```

with testdata.xml from python docs example

```
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank updated="yes">2</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Singapore">
        <rank updated="yes">5</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
    </country>
</data>
```

And I obtain:

```
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank updated="yes">2</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <Capital>Vaduz</Capital><gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E" />
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W" />
    <Capital>Vaduz</Capital></country>
    <country name="Singapore">
        <rank updated="yes">5</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N" />
    </country>
</data>
```

Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code actually add it twice:

1. `newnode = et.SubElement(firstcountrynode,"Capital")`
2. `firstcountrynode.insert(2,newnode)`

See the code below that adds it only once

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank updated="yes">2</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Singapore">
        <rank updated="yes">5</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
    </country>
</data>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
first_country = root.find('country')
capital = ET.SubElement(first_country,'capital')
capital.text = 'Vaduz'
ET.dump(root)
```